# How can I edit a line of image metadata?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, metadata, jpeg, exif

Ive tried to follow [this](https://auth0.com/blog/read-edit-exif-metadata-in-photos-with-python/) guide, and ive got this code:

```
from exif import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

with open(f"images/salt-palace.jpg", "rb") as salt_palace_file:
    salt_palace = Image(salt_palace_file)

    salt_palace.image_description = "The Salt Palace Hotel in Salt Lake City."
    salt_palace.copyright = "Copyright 2024 (Your name here)"

print(f"Description: {salt_palace.image_description}")
print(f"Copyright: {salt_palace.copyright}")
with open('images/salt-palace-updated.jpg', 'wb') as updated_salt_palace_file:
    updated_salt_palace_file.write(salt_palace.get_file())
```

I want the program to save the salt-palace-update.jpg with description metadata, and then once that works go and edit the metadata, but I get a corrupted salt-palace-updated.jpg file instead. I'm fairly new to coding, so I don't know why this is happening, I have all the files in the right place with the right names.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works completely fine. The output JPG isn't corrupt and I can see the metadata. However, pay attention that importing `Image` from `PIL` then from `exif` will make you use the second `Image` from exif. I've edited the question but it's not approved yet. NOTE: I've tested it on Linux, maybe if you're on Windows it's different.

Comment: I've tested it on my windows machine and it's working.